# sum of positive entries until a negative occurs in R

Tags: r

As an example I have a vector of 20 mixed positive and negative integers. 
I would like a generate a new vector where every positive integer is added together until a negative integers occurs and then every negative is added until a positive occurs again.

e.g. `2 4 3 -4 -4 -3 -2 3 4 5 2 5 -4 -4 -3 -3 3 4 5`  would become `9 -13 19 -14 12`.

What sort of code should I use?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#DATA
set.seed(1)
x = sample(c(1, -1), 20, TRUE) * sample(1:20, 20, TRUE)
x
# [1]  19   5 -14  -3   6  -8  -1  -8 -18   7  10  12 -10   4 -17  14 -16  -3  15  -9

sapply(split(x, with(rle(x > 0), rep(1:length(values), lengths))), sum)
#  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12 
# 24 -17   6 -35  29 -10   4 -17  14 -19  15  -9
```

Comment: A+ solution @d.b!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `tapply` with a grouping built from `diff`, `abs`, `sign`, and `cumsum`.

Using d.b's data, the result is

```
unname(tapply(x, cumsum(c(0, abs(diff(sign(x))))), sum))
 [1]  24 -17   6 -35  29 -10   4 -17  14 -19  15  -9
```

sign returns -1, 1, and 0 depending on the value of its input. `diff` will determine where changes in sign occur, `abs` turns `diff` into and indicator, stripping off the negative values and `cumsum` is used to build groups for `tapply`.